# How to play a youtube video in side-by-side view on Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I'm trying to make an Android App and I need help.

Do you have any idea how to play a online video (like a video on Youtube) in side-by-side view at the very same time by using Android WebView?

so, when I watch a Youtube video, I want to be able to have two views on left and right side on My Android SmartPhone Screen, and play and control the same video both on left and right views at the very same time.

Regards.

----2nd Feb, edited----

following things I've tried and failed.

・using Youtube API, get 3gp address, and try to play it with VideoView

・Using draw method and getDrawingCache method of WebView

・using onShowCustomView of WebView

Comment: post some of your efforts so far, i mean whatever you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a html5 video player like [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com) or Sublime Video.  You will need to create some javascript with each of these that fires the left and right video at the same time.

You can also look at what this guys did for some more inspiration.

http://html5demos.com/two-videos

The trick is getting the videos to fire at the same time if you need them in sync. It's not easy to achieve if you don't control the source video and server as you are relying on an outside party to do this. YouTube is **NOT** a good choice for serving your videos if you need them to be in sync as you can't guarantee the video load and launch times, or control if an ad will get injected into the video stream.

Comment: thanks for the comment. To start youtube video in two views at the same time is really tough,,,, I hope Android had a class like CAReplicatorLayer in iOS...